# Facebook PHP SDK - get user phone

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want ask you if is possible get fb user phone through facebook sdk api.

I look to the permission list, i didnt find anything. Is it some way to get the information about phone ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible, as it's a personal information.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant . Check out the list of permissions:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/user-friend-permissions/